# Symfony2 : Fatal Error: Call to a member function loadTemplate() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony

I try to upgrade my symfony2 project to symfony3 (I have moved from twig 1.2 to twig 2.0, and upgrade some other bundles like fos_user bundle, braincrafted/bootstrap bundle... ) and I encounter an error :

```
Fatal Error: Call to a member function loadTemplate() on a non-object
```

The detailed log is :

```
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
CRITICAL - Fatal Error: Call to a member function loadTemplate() on a non-object
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Call to a member function loadTemplate() on a non-object" at /my/path/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Form/TwigRendererEngine.php line 156
```

The error triggers for the first template containing Form blocks. If I remove the form blocks (e.g {{form_start}} or {{form_widget(...)}}), the errors appears for another template with form elements.

Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use any form theme ? Have you tried to disable them ? And if you `{{ dump(form) }}`, do you see a well-formed form ?

Comment: What do you mean by "form theme" ? I use the bundle braincrafted/bootstrap but obviously I have the same error when it is disabled

If I {{dump(form)}}, I get the dump detail on screen but have still the same error just below...

Comment: Well, a form theme is a twig template you use to customize form rendering. It can be defined directly in twig files, or in the configuration if you apply it to all your forms. Braincrafted bootstrap bundle uses one, did you try to remove it from your config.yml ? It looks like : `twig: form: resources: - BraincraftedBootstrapBundle:Form:bootstrap.html.twig`

Comment: Yes I have tried to disabled it and unfortunately nothing change...

Comment: sorry, no more ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for the while

I have changes my composer from  "sensio/distribution-bundle": "5.0", to      "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0", it seems that there was some big change in the code...

I am still not in version 3.0 but now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled BraincraftedBootstrapBundle.
I have added a print_r in TwigRendererEngine.php

```
protected function loadResourcesFromTheme($cacheKey, &$theme)
{
    print_r($theme); // added for debug
    if (!$theme instanceof \Twig_Template) {
        /* @var \Twig_Template $theme */
        $theme = $this->environment->loadTemplate($theme);
    }
    ...
```

to get the name of the template which trigger the error.

It seems to be "form_div_layout.html.twig"

When BraincraftedBootstrapBundle is activate, the template name is  BraincraftedBootstrapBundle:Form:bootstrap.html.twig (which use form_div_layout.html.twig)

Does this could help you ? Thanks